# Prestashop 1.6/1.7: require "autoload.php" in a PHP script in the "web" public folder results in an error 500 (script without namespace)

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

In `mydockercontainer:<mysite>/web/`, which is the public directory of my NGINX server Docker's container, I am writting a PHP script which consists in a simple class, out of Prestashop 1.6/1.7 (site is Prestashop 1.7 but I would want to write code in 1.6 for project reasons).

This "simple class" is: `mydockercontainer:<mysite>/web/gateway/gateway.php`. As you can see it's not a module, nor an overriding of a controller, or something else related to Prestashop. it's just a vanilla PHP script.

However, this script, `gateway.php`, needs to use some Prestashop's objects. For example `Order`.

When I try to instanciate `Order`, I have this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Order' not found in /var/www/html/gateway/requestHandler.php:47 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/gateway/requestHandler.php(17): RequestHandler->handleOrderUpdate() #1 /var/www/html/gateway/wakeup.php(5): RequestHandler->handleRequest() #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/gateway/gateway.php on line 47

So at the beginning of this script, I added the following line: `require_once '../autoload.php';`. it raises a new error: ERROR 500 but I can't figure out the logs.

Please note that my PHP script doesn't have any namespace since it's in a way out of Prestashop.

**What could I do to be able to use an object Prestashop 1.6/1.7 (preference: 1.6) class such as `Object` in a simple PHP script which is not a Prestashop controller/module/etc.?**

## Code Snippet

The following code is not entire at all but is sufficient for the question.

File: `mydockercontainer:<mysite>/web/gateway/gateway.php` (`web` being the public directory of my Prestashop 1.7 site):

```
<?php
require_once '../autoload.php';

class Gateway {
    private $request;

    private function handleOrderUpdate() {
        $ps_order = new Order($this->request['id']);    
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to initiate Prestashop core and use PS objects in a external script you'll need to include

```
../config/config.inc.php
```

Including autoload.php will not work.

Comment: `require_once '../config/config.inc.php';` indeed works. Thank you.